# How to run an installed python egg?

Tags: python

Everywhere I go, I see tutorials about hot to install a python egg, but there is no description about how to run that.

I installed

```
easy_install autobahntestsuite
```

How can I run any python installed software?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the program.  If it is a library, then when using `import`.  It is a program, then run the program.  For instance, for the package you are referring to:

```
$ wstest --help
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the docs for specific python egg/package for how to use it.

E.g. for autibahntestsuite you mentioned, you should look at http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/installation for more info